# Compare two linux systems

Tags: ssh, hardware, dd

I was looking for an answer for few hours, but I am still not sure how to compare two Linux Systems with each other. I have an access to them via ssh.

What I was trying: Previously I thought that the best idea of comparing two systems is make an image of those system using dd and then compare them (but I don't know how, yet). Making a copy of the first system took a few minutes, but when i tried to do the same on the second machine - well, I was waiting 24 h and then I killed the process. Sth went wrong.

Command:

```
ssh -v -i /path/to/key ubuntu@ipAddress "sudo dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -1 -" | pv | sudo dd of=image.gz
```

(-v was unnecessarily, my mistake) showed me:

```
debug1: Sending command: sudo dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -1 -
```

and a day later aftyer kill

```
 debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
    64.0KiB 22:03:20 [ 845miB/s] [<=>                                              ]
    debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
    Killed by signal 2.
```

Did I something wrong?

Ok, that was the first problem, but the thing is, that I want to compare two systems and I am not even sure if this method is correct. Can I compare two .gz files/images? Any software for that?

Comment: "I want to compare two systems and I am not even sure if this method is correct." sure that is what "diff" is for but ... it will not report differences on the files in the tar file. What do you expect the output to be? A compressed file does not need to compress the same way on 2 systems.  You are better off diff'ing the 2 systems.

Comment: I would suggest to use "rsync" with the "dry-run" feature or create a directory tree with files and sizes and use "git".

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"?

Comment: @Rinzwind rsync looks good, I will read more about it - I have never used it. What do I expect the output to be? Well, I think that system files which I could compare (previously I thought thai diff could be helpful) and check if hardware is the same. Those VM are empty, I have to check hardware and compare it, because I want to build the same VM as the second one.

Comment: This is an answer for @Fiximan too, thanks for response guys. I have no knowledge in this kind of tasks. I just try to compare two VM with ssh access only

Comment: see if my answer works :) not to familiar with git but that could be an option too.

Comment: you're comparing file-systems if you're comparing a `dd`.. The systems could differ if the same commands were executed on two originally identical boxes, but commands were execeuted in slightly different order (ie. packages added in different order), thus you'll see differences as you outline when in reality they ARE identical .. thus I'd look at package & config differences rather than comparing *fs*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you do not want a package comparison but an actual difference between 2 systems.

2 options I can think of:

- You could copy the whole 2nd machine and put it in a directory on the 1st machine. Let's assume `/opt/` is empty on your machine you could put `/etc/` in `/opt/etc/` and do a ...

  ```
  diff -ru /etc /opt/etc
  ```
- use `rsync` with the dry-run option from system1:

  ```
  rsync -navrc --delete /etc/* {system2}:/etc/
  ```

  -n (or --dry-run), -v verbose, -r recursive, -a archive mode, -c checksum check (must have: it will report false positives without it). --delete to have it show files not present on system1.

Do this for the normal directories (`/var/`, `/home/`, `/etc/` etc) and not temporary filesystems like `/tmp/`, `/proc/`.